# Java HTTP request not working as expected

Tags: java

I have a Java web application at my company that provides me with some server status data at a url. For example...

```
Server1 - Red
Server2 - Green
Server3 - Amber
```

Every time a request comes in at the url the web application sends request parameters back to the JSP and then the JSP loops through the request parameters and displays information on the page (pretty standard).

I have a requirement to get access to that same data but want to use the data for another purpose. My brilliant idea was to try and create a java application to send a http request to the same URL and try and get the request parameters.

I've done that but it returns me back all the HTML displayed to the user. Is there a way that I can grab only the request parameters in a similar way to the JSP?

The code I'm using is at http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-send-http-post-request

Same of jsp as requested....

```
<tbody>
    <s:iterator value="healthCheckItems.entrySet()">
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><s:checkbox name="%{value.category}Checked" fieldValue="true"/></td>
        <td><a href="<s:url action="%{value.action}"/>"><s:text name="%{value.category}"/></a></td>
        <td align="center">
            <s:if test="%{value.status.toString() == 'GREEN'}">
                <img src="img/green.png" width="20px" />
            </s:if>
            <s:elseif test="%{value.status.toString() == 'AMBER'}">
                <img src="img/amber.png" width="20px" />
            </s:elseif>
            <s:elseif test="%{value.status.toString() == 'RED'}">
                <img src="img/red.png" width="20px" />
            </s:elseif>
        </td>
        <td align="center"><s:property value="value.displayLastCheckTime"/></td>
      </tr>
    </s:iterator>
```

Comment: So..to get this straight: you have an URL that you call providing some parameters and you get the information in return displayed in browser? Now you want to call the same URL and get the same data in a java application?

Comment: Yup that's right. I was hoping from my new java application that i would b able to loop through the request parameters just like the jsp does. But I'm not sure you can do that. Can you? Or else is there another sneaky way?

Comment: can you post some pieces of the JSP? to understand what you are dealing with?

Comment: posted sample JSP. I've been reading some stuff here (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagi.html) about forwarding a request from one webapp to another. Is that an option?

Comment: interesting it would be to find out what is the JSP calling - it should call some service layer functionality. Is it so?